# Populating html table from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I have a json database from which I am trying to populate an html table.

```js
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
  var level = readLevelFromFile('data.json');
            
            var row, col;
            for(row = 0; row < level.layout.rowNum; row++) {
             tr=$('</tr>')
             
             
             for(col = 0; col < level.layout.colNum; col++){
              tr.append("<td>" + level.stage.Name + "<td>"
             }
             
             
             $("#plant").append(tr); 
        }
            });
     
 </script>
    
    
    <title>PPWebGame</title>
</head>
<body>
 <table id="plant"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
{
 "layout": [
 {"rowNum":5,"colNum":5,"stageNum":6,"agvNum":2,"vesselNum":3}

 ],
 "stage": [
 {"Name":"Liquid_A","ID":0,"Occupied":0,"Position_x":5,"Position_y":4 },
 {"Name":"Liquid_B","ID":1,"Occupied":0,"Position_x":5,"Position_y":3 },
 {"Name":"Mix","ID":2,"Occupied":0,"Position_x":5,"Position_y":2 },
 {"Name":"Heat","ID":3,"Occupied":0,"Position_x":5,"Position_y":1 },
 {"Name":"Discharge","ID":4,"Occupied":0,"Position_x":3,"Position_y":1 },
 {"Name":"Clean","ID":5,"Occupied":0,"Position_x":1,"Position_y":1 }
 ],
  }
```

The code doesn't do anything. Also, I want to assign the position of the table entry according to the 'tag' field in 'Stage'. Thanks.

Comment: What is a JSON Database? Are you attempting to access a web service or are you attempting to read data formatted as JSON which is stored in a database?

Comment: You have an inconsistency with the formatting of your data and the way you're trying to access it. `level.layout` is an`Array`, you're trying to access it like it's an `Object`. There's are also a few syntax errors.